How to fix the problem of importing a component that needs next/headers
enter image description here
I am using Next JS. and I working on app folder on server component as shown above. When I add the API call I got this error:

Error:
× You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/ directory. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/
│ react-essentials#server-components
│
│
╭─[/Users/amjadshadid/Desktop/dashboard/src/lib/clients/serverClient.ts:1:1]
1 │ import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
· ───────────────────────────────────────
2 │
3 │ import axios from 'axios';

I am expecting that when I click on button run this handler handleGenerateReport
GenerateCSVDialog.tsx file
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { GenerateCSVDialogClient } from '@/app/[locale]/[tenant]/courses/[courseId]/learners/generateCSVDialogClient';
import { apiServerClient } from '@/lib/clients/serverClient';

export async function GenerateCSVDialog({ isOpen, setOpen, courseId }: { isOpen: boolean; courseId: string; setOpen: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>; }) {
  const handleGenerateReport = async () => {
      const res = await apiServerClient.get(`/api/fx/learners/v1/learners/${decodeURIComponent(courseId)}/`, {
        params: {
          download: "csv",
          tenant_ids: 107,
        },
      });
  };

  return (
    <GenerateCSVDialogClient
      isOpen={isOpen}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      onGenerateReport={handleGenerateReport}
    />
  );
}

And the implementation of serverClient.ts file is:
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

import axios from 'axios';

import { NEXT_LOCALE_COOKIE, defaultLocale } from '@/i18n';
import { getEdxSessionCookieName, getSession } from '@/lib/auth';
import { getCSRFToken } from '@/lib/clients/csrf/client';
import { BackendAuthError } from '@/lib/clients/errors';

export const apiServerClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'X-Mediator-Name': 'NELC Next.js Dashboard',
    'User-Agent': 'nelc-dashboard',
  },
});

apiServerClient.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
  // Setting request language
  config.headers['Accept-Language'] =
    cookies().get(NEXT_LOCALE_COOKIE)?.value || defaultLocale;

  // Setting session ID and tenant base.
  const { isAuthenticated, id: sessionId, tenant } = await getSession();
  const cookieName = getEdxSessionCookieName();

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    config.headers.Cookie = `${cookieName}=${sessionId}`;
    config.baseURL = tenant.lms_root_url;
  }

  if (['post', 'put', 'delete'].includes(config.method || '')) {
    const csrfToken = await getCSRFToken();
    config.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken;
    config.headers['Referer'] = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL;

    config.headers.Cookie = `csrftoken=${csrfToken};${config.headers.Cookie}`;
  }

  return config;
});

apiServerClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    if (
      error.response.status === 403 &&
      process.env.REDIRECT_ON_BACKEND_NOT_AUTHENTICATED === 'true'
    ) {
      if (typeof window === 'undefined') throw new BackendAuthError(error);
      else window.location.href = '/signin?re=1';
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);



When using nextjs you have to specify components by what type they are, either client or server. Client are functional components that render on the client where as server components are for things like requests and server functions.(click to see docs)
For functional components you add 'use client' at the top of the component code. For the api requests you should create a server components with 'use server' at the top and then create a 'use client' / functional component that uses the request function.
One of the main things to add for CRA to Next is 'use client'; addition above all imports on every functional component.

example of use client
'use client';
 
import { useState } from 'react';
 
export default function LikeButton() {
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
 
  function handleClick() {
    setLikes(likes + 1);
  }
 
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Like ({likes})</button>;
}

example of use server
'use server'

import { addCommentToCourse } from '@/data/course'

export async function addComment(data, courseId) {
  const response = await addCommentToCourse(data, course);
  return response;
}


Did you try doing as the error suggested and move the server code outside of the pages directory? (pages is for client-only code and helpers)

Thank you for your answer, I tried to add 'use server' but after putting it i got an infinite number of rendering. and the app will down!

Where did you try adding it? lets backtrack to the original issue - the only error is because you are trying to import next headers from a non server component within the pages directory....if you are going to make serverClient a server type file then it should be moved outside of the page folder and into its own server folder https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns
